# Inverse bit in Chinese Remainder Theorem

Tags: number-theory

I need to solve the system of equations:

$$x \equiv 13 \mod 11$$
$$3x \equiv 12 \mod 10$$
$$2x \equiv 10 \mod 6.$$

So I have reduced this to

$$x \equiv 2 \mod 11$$
$$x \equiv 4 \mod 10$$
$$x \equiv 2 \mod 3$$

so now I can use CRT. So to do that, I have done

$$x \equiv \{ 2 \times (30^{-1} \mod 11) \times 30 + 4 \times (33^{-1} \mod 10) \times 33 + 2 \times (110^{-1} \mod 3) \times 110 \} \mod 330$$

$$= \{ 2 (8^{-1} \mod 11) \cdot 30 + 4(3^{-1} \mod 10)\cdot33 + 2(2^{-1} \mod 3) \cdot 110 \} \mod 330$$

but now I'm stuck on what to do. What do the inverse bits means? If I knew that I could probably simplify the rest myself.

Comment: An modular inverse $a^{-1}$ of an element $a$ modulo $n$ is any number which satisfies: $$a\cdot a^{-1}\equiv1 \pmod{n}$$

Comment: Do those have anything to do with [modular multiplicative inverses](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_multiplicative_inverse)?

Comment: That should be $2^{-1} \mod 3$.

Comment: It might just be easier to combine $x\equiv 2\pmod 3$ and $x\equiv 2\pmod {11}$ to $x\equiv 2\pmod {33}$ directly.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Yeah, sorry, fixed that.

Comment: @RossMillikan Yeah sorry, another typo. It should've been $13 \mod 11$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider $3 \mod 5$. If I multiply this by $2$, I get $2 \cdot 3 \mod 5 \equiv 1 \mod 5$. Thus when I multiply by $2$, I get the multiplicative identity. This means that I might call $3^{-1} = 2 \mod 5$.

Comment: Is there a quick way of working this out or is it trial and error? Would Bernoulli's Identity work here?

Comment: @Kaish Seriously, that should be covered in your class. If you want $a^{-1}\pmod b$ then you want to solve $ax+by=1$, and then $x$ is your inverse.

Answer (score 1):

Solving the first two equations simultaneously, you get x = 24(mod 110). Solving this result and the third equation simultaneously, you get x = 134(mod 330).

Answer (score 0):

The meaning of [modular inverses](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_multiplicative_inverse) has been explained. There is also a small error that needs fixing: $\rm\:mod\ 11:\ x\equiv 12\:\Rightarrow\:x\equiv 1\ \ (not\,\ 2).\:$ Also, brute-force Chinese remainder is usually not the most efficient method of solution. For example, here is a simpler method (no inverses needed).

$\rm mod\ 11\!:\ x\equiv 1\:\Rightarrow\: x = 1\!+\!11j.\:$ So $\rm\:mod\ 10\!:\ 4 \equiv x = 1\!+\!11j\equiv 1+j\:\Rightarrow\:j\equiv 3,\:$ so $\rm\:j = 3\! +\! 10k,\:$ thus $\rm\:x = 1\!+\!11j = 1\!+\!11(3\!+\!10k) = 34\!+\!110k.\:$ So $\rm\:mod\ 3\!:\ 2\equiv x\equiv 34\!+\!110k\equiv 1\!-\!k\:\Rightarrow\:k\equiv -1\equiv 2,\:$ i.e. $\rm\:k = 2\!+\!3n.\:$ Hence $\rm\:x = 34\!+\!110k = 34\!+\!110(2\!+\!3n) = 254\!+\!330n$.